# Edit field name in response body

Tags: spring, rest, http, interceptor, body-parser

I recieve data from third party api from REST request.

`{"Category":
   {"Name":"name123",
     "Hint":"hint"},`

...
But problem is that field names starts with upper case.

I think one solution can be @JsonProperty("Category")
but it takes a lot of time...

There are a lot of requests wicth this problem and this will help me so much. Thx ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution.

`ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
        QuestionnaireDto questionnaireDto = objectMapper.readValue(response.getBody().toString(), QuestionnaireDto.class);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Jackson custom PropertyNamingStrategy: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/how-to-use-propertynamingstrategy-in-jackson.html

Giver your scenario you will want to build a strategy like this:

```java
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.MapperConfig;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedField;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.introspect.AnnotatedMethod;

public class MyNameStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategy
 {
  @Override
  public String nameForField(MapperConfig
                       config,
   AnnotatedField field, String defaultName) {
     return convert(defaultName);

  }
  @Override
  public String nameForGetterMethod(MapperConfig
                       config,
   AnnotatedMethod method, String defaultName) {
     return convert(defaultName);
  }

  @Override
  public String nameForSetterMethod(MapperConfig
                       config,
    AnnotatedMethod method, String defaultName) {
   String a = convert(defaultName); 
   return a;
  }

  public String convert(String defaultName )
  {
   char[] arr = defaultName.toCharArray();
   if(arr.length !=0)
   {
    if ( Character.isLowerCase(arr[0])){
     char upper = Character.toUpperCase(arr[0]);
     arr[0] = upper;
    }
   }
   return new StringBuilder().append(arr).toString();
  }

 }
```

In the class you want the parsed JSON, simply use the created strategy:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new MyNameStrategy());
```